# VBA 'incompatible type' error, reformatting csv files

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm starting up a shopify shop and my boss needs me to complete the info about already existing products. I have scraped the info using a web scraper, downloaded it as a csv and converted to0 a worksheet. I have all the products on a separate sheet in the same workbook.

That means i need to copy the info of a certain scraped cell, based on the model nr found in another row on the same column - to the product worksheet, set up in a similar way.
In my head, the code should be

```
If Product nr = Model nr Then
    copy ScrapedValue to ProductSpecs
End IF
```

My error here is that it on line 10 - the if statement - it returns error "incompatible types".
Does anybody know how to convert these types to the correct type ( I guess it should be a string... ) or know a better way?

```
Sub CompareTwoRanges()

    Set rngDestination = Application.InputBox("Select the Destination Range, where the info will be pasted", "CompareTwoRanges", "", Type:=8)
    Set rngTitle = Application.InputBox("Select the Title Range, the range which will be searched for a name match.", "CompareTwoRanges", "", Type:=8)
    Set rngSourceRange = Application.InputBox("Select the Source Range, where the info is copied from", "CompareTwoRanges", Type:=8)
    Set rngSearchRange = Application.InputBox("Select the Search Range/modellnr, which name should match the title range.", "CompareTwoRanges", Type:=8)
     
    For Each c1 In rngDestination
        For Each c2 In rngSourceRange
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(CStr(Cells(nuvarandeRad, rngSearchRange.Columns(1))), CStr(Cells(CrtRow, rngTitle.Clumns(1))))) = True Then
                Cells(CrtRow, rngDestination.Columns(1)) = Cells(nuvarandeRad, rngSourceRange.Columns(1))
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `rngTitle.Clumns(1)` ??

Comment: `Cells` uses the column *index* (or letter) as its second argument. You're passing it a range.